Laplace Transform of time evolution of Amplitudes involving correlation functions
The correlation function is given by
$$
G_{ij}(t-t')= g_{i} g_{j} e^{(i\omega_{i0}-\frac{\Gamma_{0}}{2})t-(i\omega_{j0}-\frac{\Gamma_{0}}{2})t'}
$$
With the time evolution of amplitudes being given by
$$
\frac{dc_{1}}{dt}=-\int_{0}^{t}[G_{11}(t-t')c_{1}(t')dt']-\int_{0}^{t}[G_{12}(t-t')c_{2}(t')dt']\\
 \frac{dc_{2}}{dt}=-\int_{0}^{t}[G_{21}(t-t')c_{1}(t')dt']-\int_{0}^{t}[G_{22}(t-t')c_{2}(t')dt']
$$
for,
$$
\omega_{1}=\omega_{2}=\omega_{0}
$$
$$
 e^{\frac{\Gamma t}{2}}\frac{dc_{1}}{dt}=-\int_{0}^{t}[ g_{1}^{2} e^{\frac{\Gamma_{0}t'}{2}}c_{1}(t')dt']-\int_{0}^{t}[g_{1} g_{2} e^{\frac{\Gamma_{0}t'}{2}}c_{2}(t')dt']\\
  e^{\frac{\Gamma t}{2}} \frac{dc_{2}}{dt}=-\int_{0}^{t}[g_{2} g_{1} e^{\frac{\Gamma_{0}t'}{2}}c_{1}(t')dt']-\int_{0}^{t}[g_{2}^{2} e^{\frac{\Gamma_{0}t'}{2}}c_{2}(t')dt'] 
$$
I have tried to take the Laplace transform of the equation by making use use of the Laplace transformation rules:
$$
\bigtriangleup\{\ f'(t)\}=s\bigtriangleup\{\ f(t)\}-f(0)\\
 \bigtriangleup\{\ \int_{0}^{t} f(t)dt\}=\dfrac{\bigtriangleup\{\ f(t)\}}{s}\\
 \bigtriangleup\{\ f(t)\} = F(s)\\
 \bigtriangleup\{\ e^{at} f(t)\}=F(s-a)
$$
for which I got,
$$
 (s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})G_{1}(s)-c_{1}(0)=-g_{1}^{2}\frac{G_{1}(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}{(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}-g_{1}g_{2}\frac{G_{2}(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}{(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}\\
 (s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})G_{2}(s)-c_{2}(0)=-g_{2}g_{2}\frac{G_{1}(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}{(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}-g_{2}^{2}\frac{G_{2}(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}{(s-\frac{\Gamma}{2})}\\
$$
where I have taken
$$
G_{1}(s)=\bigtriangleup\{\ c_{1}(t)\}\\
$$
$$
G_{2}(s)=\bigtriangleup\{\ c_{2}(t)\}\\
$$
I am not sure if I have done it correctly and if I have not I would appreciate any suggestions on doing it correctly

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Hi Ashish, could you please make your question more clear? What kind of correlation function you consider? Why do you need to make a Laplace transform? What result do you expect and which steps cause difficulties in your derivation? Also, please check the LaTeX formatting of the equations and don't forget to use the preview before submitting your edits.

I was trying to find out the exact solutions of a decaying spontaneously 3-level V type system as mentioned in Wen-ju Gu and Gao-xiang Li**(DOI: 10.1103/PhysRevA.85.014101)**
It turns out, I was going the wrong way about it. I could have made use of the Laplace transformation formula $$ L[\int_{0}^{t}f(t-t')g(t')dt']=F(s)G(s)$$
where $$L[f(t)]= F(s)$$ and $$L[g(t)] = G(s)$$.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
